# background of a LinearLayout covering its content

Tags: android

I have this markup:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/authorDetails"
   style="@style/authorDetails">

<ImageView  
   android:id="@+id/authorPic"
   style="@style/authorPic" />   

<TextView  
   android:id="@+id/authorName"
   style="@style/authorName"
   android:text="author name" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this style:

```
 <style name="authorDetails">
      <item name="android:layout_below">@id/header</item>
      <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
      <item name="android:layout_height">89dip</item>
      <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>      
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg</item>        
   </style>  

   <style name="authorPic">
      <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
      <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
      <item name="android:src">@drawable/xxx</item>
   </style>

   <style name="authorName">
      <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
      <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
   </style>
```

and u know what?

the background of the LinearLayout covers the content (ImageView and TextView). Why is that? I dont get it! if I take out the declaration about the LinearLayout bg the content re-appears.

help please!

Comment: hm, strange. have you tried setting a higher layout_weight for the imageview and textview? would that help?
does the same problem occur when you apply properties directly and not via styles (just for testing)?

Comment: no it didnt help :( layout_weight has to do with the space occupied by the elements in a LinearLayput and not with the order in which the views are stacked. plus those 2 views are contained in the LinearLayout so they shouldnt get overlapped by their container. boo! anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

I have also came across this issue and although this question has asked a long time ago I'm posting this response as it may help someone who reads this thread. From what I saw in my case the problem was caused by a 9patch image which I was using as a background. In 'nourdine' case it might be that the '@drawable/bg' file is a 9patch one. Using a plain image should solve the issue.